# How do I "edit grub to add iomem=relaxed"?

Tags: boot, grub2, configuration

- Ubuntu 18.04 64bit
- libreboot
- flashrom 0.99

The matter is beyond my skills.

I want to [flash libreboot on a gigabyte mainboard](https://libreboot.org/docs/install/ga-g41m-es2l.html).

I got the ROM file, renamed it 
to `libreboot.rom` and tnstalled flashrom.
Then I ran the command

```
flashrom -p internal:dualbiosindex=0 -w libreboot.rom
```

But it did not work.

I was told to edit grub to add `iomem=relaxed`.

At the Ubuntu location **Computer > etc > default > grub**, the `grub` file has:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Shall I edit

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="iomem=relaxed quiet splash"
```

with nano?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nano` but personally I do everything with `gedit` both in my regular user account and with `sudo`. In this case `sudo` is needed so it would be:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="iomem=relaxed quiet splash"
```

- Save the file
- Exit `gedit`
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Type `reboot`

After rebooting type:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

You will see your changes in effect. Whether everything works or not is a different story :)